# API Endpoint For Google Admin Reports Meet Feedback Score

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm looking for an endpoint for the Google Meet Feedback Score. I've implemented the Admin SDK and I can retrieve [livestream_watched and call_ended](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet#call_ended) but neither includes a Feedback Score. If I check out the Meet Quality Tool there is a way to filter based on Feedback, so I'm hoping there must be some way to retrieve the information.

[image: Meet Quality Tool Feedback Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve this information.*

#### More Information:

As you have already pointed out, the Google Meet Audit Activity Events parameters do not include the feedback score for the meet.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Admin SDK component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102), with the `Feature Request` template.

#### References:

- [Google Meet Audit Activity Events | Reports API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet)
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)